# Are the Anchor and Dock properties mutually exclusive in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

It seems that the Dock property can be implemented in terms of acnhoring, for example `listBox.Dock = DockStyle.Left;` is equivalent to (in my small test project):

```
listBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
listBox.Height = form.ClientSize.Height;
```

Additionally, you can set the Anchor to `AnchorStyles.Right` which would contradict `DockStyle.Left`.

So I did some testing and it seems that changing the `Dock` resets the `Anchor` and vice-versa:

```
Action Print = ()=>Console.WriteLine("Anchor: " + listBox.Anchor + ";; Dock: " + listBox.Dock);
listBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
Print();
listBox.Dock = DockStyle.None;
Print();
listBox.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
Print();
listBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top;
Print();
listBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
Print();
```

This is the output:

```
Anchor: Top, Bottom, Left;; Dock: None
Anchor: Top, Bottom, Left;; Dock: None
Anchor: Top, Left;; Dock: Right
Anchor: Top, Left;; Dock: Right
Anchor: Left;; Dock: None
```

So I assume this means `Anchor` and `Dock` are mutually exclusive, and the `Anchor` property is taken into account only if the `Dock` property is set to `None`.

Is that correct?

Comment: Can you present *realistic* scenario (in layout terms) where you would use both?

Comment: @Sinatr Consider a panel with Dock: bottom. When you resize the form, should the panel preserve size, or move?

Comment: @Luaan, yes, I see. Docking is like *sticking* to one side (sticking with preserving absolute size in perpendicular direction). If you want to dock to one side **but** resize perpendicularly, then you have to replace docking with anchoring. Actually docking **is** anchoring. Docking is however more comfortable, because to anchor you have to position/size first and then apply anchor, while using dock will auto-magically position, resize and "anchor". From this follows what when you dock - you already use some anchors (using them isn't possible anymore).

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah. I still prefer the way docking was handled in Delphi, though - it was just much more smooth and easier to understand IMO. Bring to front to change the way docking works? Give me a break. I understand why it's like that *technically*, but it's just clunky. Once you understand the docking model in winforms perfectly, it's not hard to make it do what you want to do, but it's not exactly intuitive :)

Comment: @Sinatr I cannot present a realistic scenario. I simply wanted to know how things work under the hood, out of curiosity. I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes  as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 , The Anchor and Dock properties are mutually exclusive. Only one can be set at a time, and the last one set takes precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically it doesn't make any sense to use them both at the same time. Anchor says "stay this distance from the indicated edges" while Dock says "fill all of the space on this edge".

Comment: Thanks, so does this mean they are mutually exclusive as implemented by the framework? I was asking because I couldn't find any documentation on the topic.

Comment: If it isn't documented then the behavior is undefined and you can't rely on it. You'd have to decompile the source code or experiment to find out all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed exclusive. In properties panel, when you dock a control it forgets about anchor settings, and when you anchor it it forgets about dock settings.
However, in some cases you may need a combination  of both.
Let's say you have a hidden bottom-docked progress bar which you would like to push up a bottom-docked datagridview when executing a long task.
But you want to keep the datagridview top anchor when showing up the progress bar.
The solution is to place a bottom-docked progress bar and a full docked datagridview (in this order) inside an anchored panel.